# How do generics get compiled by the JIT compiler?

Tags: c#, generics, compiler-construction, jit

I know that generics are compiled by JIT (like everything else), in contrast to templates that are generated when you compile the code.
The thing is that new generic types can be created in runtime by using reflection.
Which can of course affect the generic's constraints. Which already passed the semantic parser.

Can someone explain how this is handled ?  And what exactly happens ?
 (Both the code generation and semantic check)

Comment: Constraints are not just enforced by the compiler, the jitter checks them too.  There are several not-so-trivial aspects to generics, how they get ngen-ed is particularly boggling.  It *did* take them 5 years.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I recommend reading [Generics in C#, Java, and C++: A Conversation with Anders Hejlsberg](http://www.artima.com/intv/generics.html).

> Qn 1. How do generics get compiled by the
> JIT compiler?

From the interview:

> Anders Hejlsberg: [...]
> In the CLR [Common Language Runtime],
> when you compile List, or any other
> generic type, it compiles down to IL
> [Intermediate Language] and metadata
> just like any normal type. The IL and
> metadata contains additional
> information that knows there's a type
> parameter, of course, but in
> principle, a generic type compiles
> just the way that any other type would
> compile. At runtime, when your
> application makes its first reference
> to List, the system looks to see
> if anyone already asked for
> `List<int>`. If not, it feeds into the
> JIT the IL and metadata for `List<T>`
> and the type argument int. The JITer,
> in the process of JITing the IL, also
> substitutes the type parameter.
>
> [...]
>
> Now, what we then do is for all type
> instantiations that are value
> types—such as `List<int>`, `List<long>`,
> `List<double>`, `List<float>` — we create a
> unique copy of the executable native
> code. So `List<int>` gets its own code.
> `List<long>` gets its own code.
> `List<float>`gets its own code. For all
> reference types we share the code,
> because they are representationally
> identical. It's just pointers.

---

> Qn 2. The thing is that new generic types
> can be created in runtime by using
> reflection. Which can of course affect
> the generic's constraints. Which
> already passed the semantic parser.
> Can someone explain how this is
> handled?

Essentially, IL retains a high-level view of generic types, which allows the CLR to check constraints for 'dynamically constructed' generic types  at run-time just like the C# compiler might do for 'statically constructed' types in C# source-code at compile-time.

Here's another snippet (emphasis mine):

> Anders Hejlsberg: [...]
> With a constraint, you can hoist that
> dynamic check out of your code and
> have it be verifiable **at compile time
> or load time.** When you say K must
> implement IComparable, a couple of
> things happen. On any value of type K,
> you can now directly access the
> interface methods without a cast,
> because semantically in the program
> it's guaranteed that it will implement
> that interface. Whenever you try and
> create an instantiation of that type,
> the compiler will check that any type
> you give as the K argument implements
> IComparable, or else you get a compile
> time error. **Or if you're doing it with
> reflection you get an exception.**
>
> Bruce Eckel: You said the compiler and
> the runtime.
>
> Anders Hejlsberg: **The compiler checks
> it, but you could also be doing it at
> runtime with reflection, and then the
> system checks it.** As I said before,
> anything you can do at compile time,
> you can also do at runtime with
> reflection.

Answer (score 2):

Reference types generics all become the **same** type; value type generics are instantiated **separately**.

This is because reference types are all really just `Object` references  (4 or 8 bytes), whereas value types are different and cannot be handled by a single piece of code, due to stack layout differences, etc. Therefore, instantiating multiple copies of a generic type with value types will increase the memory usage by a lot, whereas instantiating multiple copies with reference types won't.

Comment: They aren't the same type.  They share the same machine code for member functions (methods)... but each is a distinct type with its own copy of static member variables.