# How to declare a const field of a generic value type provided as generic argument

Tags: c#, generics, enums, value-type

I'm trying to define a generic class that accept as argument a value type (actually it will be an enum) and initialize a const field with it's default type.

I want something like:

```
public abstract class GenericClass<ValueType> 
    where ValueType: struct, IConvertible
{
  public const ValueType val = default(ValueType);
}
```

Unfortunately the compiler complaints (I'm using Mono but I think it's the same on .NET). The error is the following:

> error CS1959: Type parameter `ValueType' cannot be declared const

What's my error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Type parameter is not allowed for constant type.

Because a `struct` cannot be made `const` (from *C# specification 10.4 Constants*)

> The type specified in a constant declaration must be `sbyte`, `byte`, `short`, `ushort`, `int`, `uint`, `long`, `ulong`, `char`, `float`, `double`, `decimal`, `bool`, `string`, an enum-type, or a reference-type.

A kind of workaround to this limitation is to declare it as `static` `readonly`.

```
public static readonly ValueType val = default(ValueType);
```

Comment: and is there anyway to force ValueType to be a enum without using struct restriction?

Comment: `or a reference-type` part is somewhat confusing

Comment: @Heisenbug, there is not. Not at compilation time anyway

Comment: @NikitaBrizhak "or a reference-type part is somewhat confusing". Why? It makes sense... with only one possible value: `null`. :D

Comment: @CédricBignon, I guess :)

Comment: @CédricBignon But you can't make `public const T val = null;` with `where T : class` generic constraint.

Answer (score 1):

According to [its definition in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e6w8fe1b%28v=vs.80%29.aspx): a constant expression is an expression that can be evaluated completely at compiling time.

According to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5342345/how-do-generics-get-compiled-by-the-jit-compiler), that references [this interview](http://www.artima.com/intv/generics2.html):

> Anders Hejlsberg: [...] In the CLR [Common Language Runtime], when you
>   compile List, or any other generic type, it compiles down to IL
>   [Intermediate Language] and metadata just like any normal type. The IL
>   and metadata contains additional information that knows there's a type
>   parameter, of course, but in principle, a generic type compiles just
>   the way that any other type would compile. At runtime, when your
>   application makes its first reference to List, the system looks to see
>   if anyone already asked for List. If not, it feeds into the JIT
>   the IL and metadata for List and the type argument int. The JITer,
>   in the process of JITing the IL, also substitutes the type parameter.

Thus, because the type is not defined at compiling, the default value cannot be get until runtime.

Comment: actually it should be possible to evaluate it at compile time.

Comment: @Heisenbug, no. Custom struct can have a custom default constructor which can do a number of different things, which can not be evaluated

Comment: @NikitaBrizhak: Wrong.  structs cannot have custom default constructors.

Comment: @SLaks, true. I meant custom (parameterized) constructors, not sure where the word "default" came from :)