# What is the behaviour of the '==' operator for a generic type value and the 'default' keyword?

Tags: c#

Part 1 of the question:
In the following code why does `value == default` compile fine but the other alternatives do not?

```cs
bool MyEqual<T>(T value)
{
    T value2 = default;
    if (value == value2)     // Error: Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'T' and 'T'
        return true;
    if (value == default(T)) // Error: Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'T' and 'T'
        return true;
    if (value == default)    // No error
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Part 2 of the question:
In the following code, why do the first three prints show `false` and the other three show `true`?

```cs
bool MyEqual<T>(T value)
{
    if (value == default)
        return true;
    return false;
}

Console.WriteLine($"{MyEqual<int>(0)}");                  // False
Console.WriteLine($"{MyEqual<int>(default)}");            // False
Console.WriteLine($"{MyEqual<int>(default(int))}");       // False

Console.WriteLine($"{MyEqual<string>(null)}");            // True
Console.WriteLine($"{MyEqual<string>(default)}");         // True
Console.WriteLine($"{MyEqual<string>(default(string))}"); // True
```

To sum it up: What is the behaviour of the expression `value == default`?

EDIT: Please do not mark it as a duplicate of this other question, because that one addresses a different case, `value == default(T)` and not `value == default`:
[What does default(object); do in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432909/what-does-defaultobject-do-in-c)
Also, my question is regarding the odd behaviour when using the '==' operator as I explain above.

Comment: with generics I believe the compiler needs something like IComparable because it has no idea how to compare if something is equal to something else because it does not know the type.

Comment: First two errors are explained by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390900/cant-operator-be-applied-to-generic-types-in-c

Comment: It's fun, in your example: `bool a = default == default(T);` - no error, `T v = default; bool a = v == default(T);` - error.

Comment: What C# version? `default` isn't available before 7.1. With 7.1 and after none of the three comparisons compile, all for the same reason.

Comment: @Daniel A. White the linked "duplicate question" does not address this case, but rather a similar one: value == default(T).

Comment: The third one compiles for me on 7.1, although ReSharper doesn't like it.

Comment: `default` is just a simplified version of `default(T)`

Comment: Best reference I can find is here: https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/proposals/csharp-7.1/target-typed-default.md "The default literal can be the operand of equality operators, as long as the other operand has a type. So default == x and x == default are valid expressions, but default == default is illegal."

Comment: @DanielA.White there's more to it than that. In any case, the duplicate you linked doesn't touch on == at all, which is the specific thing that OP is asking for.

Comment: @DanielA.White if you read my question properly, you will see that is not. Right at the beginning you will see that using `default(T)` will not compile, whereas just using `default` does compile. Please read the questions thoroughly before using your privileges to lock questions.

Comment: Apparently the `value == default` invokes `ReferenceEquals` with boxing for value types (like the `int` in part 2). If you add `where T:struct` to the `bool MyEqual<T>(T value)` signature (in either part), you lose the ability to use `value == default` inside it with the error "Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'T' and 'default'". Apparently `value == default(T)` tries to invoke direct comparison instead so it fails straight away.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the context of `==` where the operand type is a generic parameter, `value == default` seems to emit equivalent IL to `value == null`, which always evaluates to *`false`* for a non-nullable value type operand.

Given:

```
static bool IsDefault<T>(T value) => value == default;
static bool IsNull<T>(T value) => value == null;
```

We get the IL:

```
.method private hidebysig static 
    bool IsDefault<T> (
        !!T 'value'
    ) cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x2050
    // Code size 10 (0xa)
    .maxstack 8

    IL_0000: ldarg.0
    IL_0001: box !!T
    IL_0006: ldnull
    IL_0007: ceq
    IL_0009: ret
} // end of method C::IsDefault

.method private hidebysig static 
    bool IsNull<T> (
        !!T 'value'
    ) cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x205b
    // Code size 10 (0xa)
    .maxstack 8

    IL_0000: ldarg.0
    IL_0001: box !!T
    IL_0006: ldnull
    IL_0007: ceq
    IL_0009: ret
} // end of method C::IsNull
```

You could be forgiven for finding this surprising.  It means, for example, that when `T` is bound to a non-nullable value type like `int`, the expression `value == default` evaluates to *`false`* for a value of `0`.  This contrasts with the inlined expression `0 == default`, which evaluates to *`true`*.

```
Console.WriteLine(IsDefault<int>(0));     // False
Console.WriteLine(IsNull<int>(0));        // False
Console.WriteLine(IsDefault<int?>(null)); // True
Console.WriteLine(IsNull<int?>(null));    // True
Console.WriteLine(IsDefault<int?>(0));    // False
Console.WriteLine(IsNull<int?>(0));       // False
```

So, clearly, for a `value` of an unconstrained generic parameter type, the expressions `value == default` and `value == default(T)` are *not* equivalent.  If legal, the latter would (presumably) evaluate to `true` if the value were null, false, or a "zeroed-out" value type (e.g., a value type where all constituent values are also defaults).

As to why `value == default(T)` does not compile, the answer is simple: the compiler does not know how to evaluate `==` for a type that is not known at compile time.  If you were to add the constraint `where T : class`, then the compiler could at least perform a reference comparison.  But as long as `T` could be a primitive type, custom value type, or reference type, the compiler doesn't know how to emit the comparison.  The correct implementation for a given instantiation of `T` might be a built-in primitive comparison, an `op_Equality` overload, or a reference comparison.  More importantly, it **may not be a supported operator at all.**  It's that last possibility that really poses a problem.

While the C#/.NET engineers could have come up with a way to defer figuring out the correct comparison until runtime, that would also mean trading a compile-time error for a runtime exception in cases where the operator is simply not applicable, and I don't find that trade very appealing

Comment: `value == default(T); value == value2` The first part of the question asks why these don't compile, do you know why?

Comment: And do you know why `value == null` generates a warning, while `value == default`doesn't? For me `value == null` is much more explicit even for value types (for which I expect it to always return false), whereas this behaviour for `value == default` seems very dubious, and IMO this is the one that should generate a warning!

Comment: Generic methods get JITed seperately for each type the method gets invoked with as discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5342345/how-do-generics-get-compiled-by-the-jit-compiler. So why can't `value  == default(T)` get JITed for each type T it is going to be invoked with?

Comment: @AvinKavish I think that's because the '==' operator is not supported out of the box for value types, so it cannot ensure that the operator 'T == T' exists. Of course it exists for the primitive types, but not for other custom structures that you may create.

Comment: Fair enough. I guess operator enforcement has to be static in a practical sense. Edit: I don't know I'm having second thoughts, is a run-time operand failure such a bad thing? We have so many dynamic dispatches already. Actually, I'm happy for it to fail because it will only fail with `value == default(T)` expressions and not all types.

Comment: I would argue the difference between `value == default` and `value == default(T)` in the context of generics is a bug. According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/default-value-expressions, there should not be any.

Comment: @GSerg It certainly feels like it *ought to be* a bug.  I find the current behavior not just counter-intuitive, but downright surprising.

Comment: @Avin it would also reduce the amount of native code sharing.  IIRC, generic method instantiations share code among similar types (all reference types; value types of the same size; etc.)

Comment: Fixed: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/36492#issuecomment-524603043